# Upper bound for $\mathbb P(|f(A+XX^T)-f(A)| > \epsilon)$, where $A$ is a fixed pd matrix and $X$ has random iid entries

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $A$ be a fixed $n$ by $n$ real symmetric positive definite matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n > 0$, and let $f(A):=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\lambda_i$, and let $X$ be a random $n$ by $k$ matrix with real iid copies distributed according to $N(0,\sigma^2/k)$.

### The regime

- $n$ is fixed (in particular, $n \not \to \infty$).
- $k \to \infty$ (in particular, $k \gg n$).

### Question

- How close is $f(A+XX^T)$ to $f(A)$ in espectation ?
- What is an upper-bound for  $\mathbb P(|f(A+XX^T)-f(A)|  > \epsilon)$?

## Observations

I've observed that $f(A+XX^T)$ is approximately $\mathcal N(\mu,s^2)$, for some $\mu \in \mathbb R$, and $s > 0$.

### Back-of-envelop calculation

By triangle inequality, one has
$$
\begin{split}
|f(A+XX^T) - f(A)| \le &|f(A+\sigma^2 I_n) - f(A)|\\
&\quad + |f(A+XX^T) - f(A+\sigma^2 I_n)|.
\end{split}
\tag{*}
$$

Note that as $k\rightarrow \infty$, $XX^T \rightarrow \sigma^2 I_n$ in probability. Thus, by the delta method, we know that $f(A+XX^T) - f(A+\sigma^2 I_n) \longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,s^2/k)$, where
$$
s^2 := n\sigma^4\|(A+\sigma^2 I_n)^{-1}\|_F^2 \le \sigma^4(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j((A + \sigma^2)^{-1})^2 \le (\sqrt{n}\sigma^2\eta(A))^2,
$$
where
$$
\begin{split}
\eta(A) &= \eta(A; \sigma^2) := \text{trace}(A+\sigma^2 I_n)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i(A)+\sigma^2)^{-1}
\le n\min(\sigma^{-2},\lambda_n(A)^{-1}).
\end{split}
$$

On the other hand,
$$
|f(A + \sigma^2 I_n) - f(A)| = \sum_{i=1}^n\log(1 + \sigma^2/\lambda_i) \le \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i(A)+\sigma^2)^{-1} = \sigma^2\eta(A).
$$

Putting everything together then gives

$$
\begin{split}
E_X|f(A+XX^T) - f(A)| &\le \sigma^2\frac{n}{\lambda_n} + E_X|f(A+XX^T)-f(A+\sigma^2 I_n)|\\
&\le \sigma^2\eta(A) + \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}} \sigma^2 \eta(A) \to \sigma^2\eta(A).
\end{split},
$$

Thus it appears that,

> To have $E|f(A+XX^T) - f(A)|$ small, it is sufficient to have $\sigma^2 \eta(A) \ll 1$ and $k \rightarrow \infty$.

This doesn't solve my problem, but it raises suspicion to what the important problem parameters could be; here, $\sigma$, $k$, and $\eta(A)$ (or $n/\lambda_n$, for an even cruder analysis).

Comment: Any reasonable answer must depend on how $\lambda_n$ is close to $0$. This is because the minimal eigenvalue of $A+XX^T$ will be of order $\sqrt{n}$ and least. So if for example $\lambda_n=e^{-n}$ then there is a huge difference between $f(A)$ and $f(A+XX^T)$ if $n$ is large.

Comment: Sure, $n$, $k$, $\lambda_1$, and $\lambda_n$, and $\sigma$ are all problem data, and so I'd expect any reasonable answer to depend on them.

Comment: The short answer is that if $\lambda_n>>n$ then you have concentration, and quantitative answers depend on regimes (for example, if all eigenvalues of $A$ are much larger than $n$ then you have good concentration). The question is too open ended for me to seriously answer. If there is a specific asymptotic regime that you care about then please write it.

Comment: $A$ is a **fixed** $n$ by $n$ matrix, where $n$ is small (say, $ n = 100$). In particular, $n$ doesn't go to $\infty$.  As for $k$, one may limit onself to the regime $k \rightarrow \infty$, if that helps. If this clarifies the situation, please let me know (so I can update the question with these poiints).

Comment: In the regime $k\to \infty$ , $XX^T\sim kI_n$. In particular, there is no hope for what you want, as $f(A+XX^T)\to\infty$. Did you mean to normalize $XX^T$? Also, what are entries $N(0,\sigma^2 I)$? are the entries real? complex?

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thanks for the comments. $X$ has real iid entries which are distributed according to $N(0,\sigma^2/k)$. See corrected question.

Comment: @oferzeitouni I've added an answer based on Berry-Esseen. I'd be grateful if you could take a look and tell me what you think. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure why one needs Berry Esseen. For all I can tell, a simple estimate based on variance would do. Namely, the difference between the eigenvalues of $XX^T$ and $1$ is, with high probability, bounded by $n$ times $1/\sqrt{k}$ (just bound the individual off-diagonal entries of $XX^T$; each such entry is a sum of independent random variables). As for your proof, sorry but I don't have the time now to check it.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thanks for pointing out that Berry-Esseen is a sub-optimal overkill for my problem. I've updated my answer with a "direct" computation which leverages sub-Gaussianity, combined with *Weyl's inequality*.

Comment: Also, one can work out the details of your suggestion above by constructing a Gershgorin confidence set for the eigenvalues of $XX^T$.  My guess is that something like this is done under the hood in the "book proof" of *Weyl's inequality*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I provide a "high-probability" **non-asymptotic** bound (see (+) below) based on [non-linear Berry-Esseen theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0177v2.pdf) developed by Iosif Pinelis. I'd be grateful if someone would kindly check that I didn't screw up anything. Thanks in advance!

---

### Main tool: non-linear Berry-Esseen theory

Let $ \mathcal H$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space with topological dual $\mathcal H^*$, and let $g:\mathcal H \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that

- $g(0)=0$,
- $g$ has linear approximant $L \in \mathcal H^*$ valid on a nonzero neighborhood of the origin, i.e there exist $\epsilon > 0,M>0$ such that

$$
|g(z) - L(z)| \le \frac{M}{2}\|z\|^2,\;\forall \|z\| \le \epsilon. \tag{1}
$$

Note that under such conditions, we automatically have that $g$ is (Fréchet) differentable at $0$ and $L=\nabla g(0)$.

Let $Z$ be a random vector on $\mathcal H$ such that $E Z = 0$ (i.e $Z$ is centered) and suppose $\tilde{\sigma} := \|L(Z)\|_{Z,2} := (E_Z|L(Z)|^2)^{1/2} < \infty$. The quantity $\tilde{\sigma}^2/k$ will play the role of a "proxy variance" for the random variable $g(Z)$. Finally, let $Z_1,\ldots,Z_k$ be iid copies of $Z$ and set $\overline{V} := (1/k)\sum_{i=1}^kZ_i$.

> **Theorem (Corollary 3.7 of [reference paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0177v2.pdf)).** *Let $p \in (2,3]$ such that $\|Z\|_{Z,p} := (E_Z\|Z\|_p)^{1/p} < \infty$. Then
> $$
> \sup_{t \in \mathbb R}\left|\mathbb P\left(\frac{g(\overline{V})}{\tilde{\sigma}/\sqrt{k}}\ge t\right)-\Phi(t)\right| \le Ck^{1-p/2},
> $$
> where $C$ is a constant which only depends on the distribution of $Z$ (in particular, $C$ is independent of the sample size $k$ and $p$).*

### Application: our problem

For our own business, we let

- $\mathcal H$ be the euclidean space of $n$ by $n$ matrices equipped with the Frobenius trace inner product $\langle B,\tilde{B}\rangle_{Fro} := \text{trace}(B^T\tilde{B})$. We denote induced norm by $\|B\|_{Fro} := \langle B,B\rangle_{Fro}^{1/2}$. Note that this space is nothing but euclidean $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ in disguise.
- Define
  $$g(B) := \begin{cases}f(B + A + \sigma^2 I_n) - f(A+\sigma^2 I_n),&\mbox{ if }B + A + \sigma^2 I_n \succ 0,\\0,&\mbox{ else.}\end{cases}
  $$
  where $f(B) := \sum_{j=1}^n\log\lambda_j(B)$.
- It's not hard to see that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $L:=g'(0) := (A+\sigma^2 I_n)^{-1}$. Moreover, $g$ has Lipschitz continuous gradient at $0$ and and so (1) is satisfied.
- For our random vector, we take $Z = RR^T-\sigma^2 I_n$, where $R \in \mathbb R^n$ is a random vector with iid entries from $N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$. Thus $XX^T-\sigma^2 I_n = (1/k)\sum_{i=1}^k Z_j =: \overline{V}$, where $Z_j = X_jX_j^T$ are iid copies of $Z$ (where $X_i$ is the $i$th column of the random $n$ by $k$ matrix $X$ in our original problem). Of course, $\|Z\|_{Z,p} < \infty$ for all $p$ (Gaussians have finite moments).
- By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, one computes
  $$
  \begin{split}
  \tilde{\sigma}^2 &= \|L(Z)\|_Z = \|L\|_{Fro}^2\|Z\|_{Z,2}^2 = \text{trace}((A+\sigma^2 I_n)^{-2})E_Z\|Z\|_2^2\\
  & \le (\sum_{j=1}^n(\lambda_j(A) + \sigma^2)^{-1})^2\cdot n \sigma^4 \le n\sigma^4\eta(A)^2 = (\sqrt{n}\sigma^2\eta(A))^2,
  \end{split}
  $$
  where
  $$
  \begin{split}
  \eta(A) &= \eta(A; \sigma^2) := \text{trace}(A+\sigma^2 I_n)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i(A)+\sigma^2)^{-1}
  \le n\min(\sigma^{-2},\lambda_n(A)^{-1}).
  \end{split}
  $$

Putting everything together, and applying the above theorem, we obtain that for every $t \ge 0$, w.p at least $\Phi(t\sqrt{k})+\mathcal O(k^{-1/2})$,

$$
|f(A+XX^T) - f(A + \sigma^2 I_n)| = |f(\overline{V}+A+\sigma^2 I_n) - f(A + \sigma^2 I_n)| \le t\sqrt{n}\sigma^2\eta(A).
$$

Combining with (*) then gives: for all $t \ge 0$, it holds w.p at least $\Phi(t\sqrt{k/n})+\mathcal O(k^{-1/2})$ that

$$
|f(A+XX^T) - f(A)| \le \sigma^2\eta(A) + t\sigma^2\eta(A) = (1+t)\sigma^2\eta(A). \tag{+}
$$

---

## Edit: Improved non-asymptotic bound for the term $|f(A+XX^T)-f(A+\sigma^2 I_n)|$

> *It has been noted in the comments section of the question that Berry-Esseen sounds like an over-kill (and might produce sub-optimal bounds for my particular problem in which everything is sub-Gaussian...). To remedy this, I'll use well-known concentration results for estimation of covariance matrices, and then Weyl's inequality. Interestingly, just as in the Berry-Esseen method above, the key requirement is that the entries of $X$ be iid with finite moments of order $2 + \epsilon$.*

By **Proposition 2.1** of [HOW CLOSE IS THE SAMPLE COVARIANCE MATRIX TO
THE ACTUAL COVARIANCE MATRIX?](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/sample-covariance.pdf), we know that for any $t \ge 0$, it holds with probability $1-2e^{-ct^2}$ that

$$
\|XX^T-\sigma^2I\| = \left\|\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^kR_iR_i^T-\sigma^2 I_n\right\| \le t\sigma^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}.
$$

Thus by *Weyl's inequality*, it holds with probability $1-2e^{-ckt^2/n}$ that

$$
\max_{1 \le i \le n} |\lambda_i(A+XX^T)-\lambda_i(A+\sigma^2)| \le \|XX^T-\sigma^2I_n\| = \left\|\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^kR_iR_i^T-\sigma^2 I_n\right\| \le t\sigma^2,
$$
and so by the triangle inequality, it holds with probability $1-2e^{-ckt^2/n}$ that

$$
\begin{split}
|f(A+XX^T)-f(A+\sigma^2 I_n)| &= \left| \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(\frac{\lambda_i(A+XX^T)}{\lambda_i(A + \sigma^2 I_n)}\right)\right|\\
& \le \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\log\left(\frac{\lambda_i(A+XX^T)}{\lambda_i(A + \sigma^2 I_n)}\right)\right| \\
& \le \sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(1 + \frac{t\sigma^2}{\lambda_i(A)+\sigma^2}\right)
\\
&\le t\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i(A)+\sigma^2)^{-1}\\
&= t\sigma^2\eta(A).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: This is what I had in mind. Thumbs up.